# "$p_s(s)ds=p_r(r)dr$" Why does this equation hold true?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

[image]

I cannot find the proof of this equation.

$p_s(s)ds = p_r(r)dr$

Why is this equation true?

For more details:

$r$ is an random variable.

$s$ is also an random variable which is transformed from random variable $r$ by a function $T$.

My professor mentioned that $p_s(s)$ and $p_r(r)$ are pdf of each random variable $s$ and $r$.

Comment: The title of the question should have something to do with the specific question itself. Imagine what would happen if everyone who needed help with a probability problem would use the title “Need help with this probability problem”.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I edited the title.

Comment: what's $P_s$ and $P_r$?

Comment: And what are $s,r$ and $T[r]$?

Comment: @Shinbt There's too much in this post that is not known to us. One way to do things is to provide a link to the PDF where you saw this, or the textbook in which you saw this. Also mention how much you know or have learned in probability theory, so that people know what notions to use when they explain things to you.

Comment: @Teresa Lisbon Sorry for the not enough informations.

Comment: @user Sorry for the not enough informations.

Comment: @Calvin Khor Sorry for the not enough informations.

Comment: I have voted to reopen your question.

Comment: @Teresa Lisbon Thanks for the help. I looked the materials that you gave me and finally understood! I really appreciate for your help :)

Comment: @user check out this one(proof). [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_unconscious_statistician)

Comment: @user From the recent link provided by OP, I have well and truly got this wrong. I apologize. The point is, I was thinking that if $s = T(r)$ then $ r = T^{-1}(s)$ and then the inverse identity struck me, and I saw a similar image on Wikipedia explaining the equality of the inverse area , which seemed to say the density of the area on both sides was the same. I will delete those comments, it seems this is basically the substitution rule after all. I would have felt really bad had I truly mislead the OP.

Comment: @Shinbt You may also frequent the chatroom [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43593/constructive-feedback) if you wish for feedback on your questions on the site. I can see you are responsive to feedback from users, keep it up.

Comment: @Teresa Lisbon Thanks!

Comment: @Shinbt Welcome. I have also, following your edits and your research following my (turned out wrong!) suggestions, given you a +1 for your efforts. Keep it up.

Comment: I think this equality follows from the fact that both $\int_{r_1}^{r_2}p_r(r)dr$ and $\int_{T(r_1)}^{T(r_2)}p_s(s)ds$ give the probability that the value of the "original" random variable is between $r_1$ and $r_2$. Probably there should be an additional condition that the function $T(r)$ is monotonic (as it shown in the figure).

Comment: @user Indeed, substitution doesn't work unless the $1-1$ nature is not maintained, hence monotonicity is very much required.